# Android fullscreen activity shows ActionBar

Tags: android

I am trying to create a fullscreen activity in Android.  I add the `FullscreenTheme` style as follows.  But the action bar still shows.

**style.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
```

The project minimum SDK is API 21 Android 5.0 Lollipop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Theme to this .

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```